# Position of the separable verb prefix

Tags: word-order

I have learned in a German grammar book that a separable verb prefix must come at the end of a main clause. The only exception I know is the second element of a comparison, which may come after the separable verb prefix. Ex: Ich spreche es schneller aus *als Sie* (= I pronounce it faster than you).

However, I have just heard the following sentence in the TV series "How to Sell Drugs Online (Fast)":

> Wir kriegen das hin mit MyTems. (= We'll figure it out with MyTems)

Shouldn't this sentence be "wir kriegen das mit MyTems hin", as the verb of the sentence is "hinkriegen" ?

Comment: For one thing, don't expect a couple of teenage hackers/drug-dealers to speak with perfect grammar. Also, German grammars in English tend to be, let's say, incomplete when it comes to details. Certain prepositional phrases can come after the second part of the verb. It's never wrong to put the second part of the verb last, so for learners that's the best policy when speaking or writing in German.

Answer (score 2):

In response to a similar question, I found [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/37853/38673) particularly helpful. Following the logic of that answer, it appears that the sentence

> Wir kriegen das hin mit MyTems.

puts the emphasis on *being able to do something*, whereas

> Wir kriegen das mit MyTems hin.

puts the emphasis on *MyTems* as being the way that the objective will be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the last part of your sentence as something on his own:

> Wir kriegen das hin, mit MyTems.

Or even more isolated:

> Wir kriegen das hin. Mit MyTems!

Not that it is always used in this way, because the usage depends on someones way of talking. Your example is also correct.